# using xpath or css : How to get something which is selected on page

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

using xpath or css : How to get something which is selected on page using following html code.
in following code, Element1 is selected on page and I wanted to find name of element that is selected on page.

```
<div id="idc" class="tre">
  <ul id="idCatT_srt_ul" class="abc">
    <li class="treN treB treSelected" title="Element1 title">
      <span class="spclass">Element1</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "selected" is a little ambiguous.  It could mean highlighted with the mouse, it could me clicked by the user or it could mean focused.  Can you clarify a little?

Comment: sorry for not being too clear...selected in this context mean element is highlighted already when page is loaded. and I'm trying to find Element that is highlighted with blue background color

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that you're looking for the `<li>` that contains `selected` you can do that with Xpath or CSS selectors like this:

**XPath**: (if I remember right...)

```
//*[contains(@class,"selected")]
```

**CSS Selectors**:

```
.treSelected
```

Comment: Hi Jweede, thank you for immediate reply. I'm looking for span text , in this example which is "Element1"